# How can we keep a text field's font size relative to the screen size?

Tags: ios, fonts, uitextfield

I have a text field and I have given it a regular font with 13 px in size.

But I want the font size to increment with respect to screen size.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can calculate the font size based on the screen's dimensions.

```
let baseWidth: CGFloat = 320 // the width of the screen where you want to use 13pt
let fontSize = 13 * (UIScreen.main.size.width / baseWidth)
let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: fontSize)
```

Comment: you mean to say I have set font size programatically by using the above formulae

Comment: @ShankarNaik Yes, you should do that.

Comment: Thanks I will try

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do this by checking, `Automatically Adjusts Font` in the `Attributes Inspector` [image: Like this]

Comment: Thanks I will try

Comment: Automatically adjusts font not available for button

Comment: I treid running the app with adjusts font/...but to my eyes font size seems same ..I tried on iPhone 7 plus and 5s